# Why can't I see nested args?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have a nested GraphQL structure.

```
export default new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Disbursement",
  fields: () => ({
    disbursementId: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
    }
    transaction: {
      type: Transaction
    }
  })
});

export default new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Transaction",
  args: {
    limit: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
    },
  },
  fields: () => ({
    transactionId: {
      type: GraphQLID
    }
  })
});
```

When I try to query the `Disbursement`, I want to be able to pass a limit to `Transaction`

```
query {
  allDisbursements {
    transaction(limit:10) {
        transactionId 
    }
  }
}
```

But I have no limit available on `Transaction`.  What am I doing wrong?  What am I missing?

Comment: you cant place args on a type, they go on a field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema is set up a bit wrong and you need to place args on a field. you want something more like the following. see launchpad example https://launchpad.graphql.com/0vrj5p80k5

```
import {
  GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLNonNull, GraphQLID, GraphQLSchema, GraphQLInt, GraphQLList } from 'graphql'

const Transaction = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "Transaction",
  fields: () => ({
    transactionId: {
      type: GraphQLID
    }
  })
})

const Disbursement = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "Disbursement",
  fields: () => ({
    disbursementId: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
    },
    transaction: {
      args: {
        limit: {
          type: GraphQLInt,
        },
      },
      type: new GraphQLList(Transaction),
      resolve (source, args) {
        return args.limit ? source.transaction.slice(0, args.limit) : source.transaction
      }
    }
  })
})

const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    allDisbursements: {
      type: new GraphQLList(Disbursement),
      resolve () {
        return [
          { disbursementId: 1, transaction: [{ transactionId: 1 }, { transactionId: 2 }] },
          { disbursementId: 2, transaction: [{ transactionId: 5 }, { transactionId: 3 }] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})




// Required: Export the GraphQL.js schema object as "schema"
export const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: Query
})
```